# How to delete files for all users Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

How do I delete files for all users in Linux Mint?

My specific scenario is that I am trying to write a script that will delete all the files out of the downloads folder for any user which logs onto the machine on logoff.

I will be using something like

`rm -rf /home/local/my-domain-name/"variable-username"/Downloads/*`

And placing it in

`/etc/init.d/`

The reason for the weird syntax is that I have added it to my domain using pbis-open.

Would %(DOMAIN_USER) work in the "variable-username" bit or will this fubar my system?

Comment: Just to clarify, each user will have a separate directory.  When a user logs off, you want to delete all files from that user's directory?  By "all users", you mean any specific user as applicable for that session?

Comment: On way might be to get a list of users (or possibly directory within ` /home/local/my-domain-name/` , and then iterate through each deleting the `/Downloads/*`

Comment: When a user logs onto the machine a directory is generated for them, when they log off I would like all files deleted from the Downloads folder only. If I can specify that it only takes place for that user then great! I didn't know you could do that.
The list of users is quite high considering it has every user from Active Directory, would it take a long time for it to call every user?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete all of the `Downloads` directories, you can use:

```
rm -rf /home/local/my-domain-name/*/Downloads
```

The shell will expand `*` to each directory under `/home/local/my-domain-name/`. The easiest way to do it on logout is to use a [PAM session hook](http://upsilon.cc/~zack/hacking/software/pam-hooks/) - use the same session hook to recreate the directory on login.

**Note** It's best to delete the entire `Downloads` directory rather than just everything below `Downloads` (ie `Downloads/*`) to prevent users creating directories starting with `.` (which `*` won't match) and bypassing the deletion.

Comment: Will the Downloads directories be recreated on login again? I do still need them.

Comment: Or would this work?

`rm -rf /home/local/my-domain-name/*/Downloads/*`

Comment: @lon0 See my expanded answer

Comment: @lon0: In a comment on the question, you say that the directory is created for them when they log on.  Why would you need to preserve the directory?